# I'm confused about Scala function and closure

Tags: scala

When I read book I saw the following is a function:

```
val plusOne=(x:Int)=>x+1
```

well, when the function invoke a variable it becomes a closure:
The following is a closure:

```
val count=1
val plusOne=(x:Int)=>x+count
```

Is that right - If a function used any variable, then it will become closure?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, that's not right.

What you are seeing there, is just a nested function. The defining feature of a *closure* is that it *closes over* its enclosing lexical environment, and thus extends the lifetime of the variables in that enclosing environment beyond the lifetime of that enclosing environment.

See this for an example:

```
def makeAdder(inc: Int) = (x: Int) => x + inc

val threeAdder = makeAdder(3)

threeAdder(20) //=> 23
threeAdder(39) //=> 42
```

Even though the method `makeAdder` has exited and thus the local variable `inc` has gone out of scope, the *closure* returned by `makeAdder` still has access to it, because it closes over the lexical environment of `makeAdder`. So, a nested function with free variables *becomes* a closure as soon as its enclosing lexical scope ends and it escapes from it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that is right.

You can read more about it on [TutorialsPoint: Scala closures](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/scala/scala_closures.htm).

This definition of a closure is not specific to scala.

Comment: That's not true for the question: `If a function used any variable, then it will become closure?`.

Answer (score -1):

I think yout Code is wrong.
If count is var..  like..

var count  = 1

Then the function value of plusOne is created and closed at runtime, so we can call it closure.
But in your example count is val type.  so the function value is always closed at compile time.. so it's not closure.